# iwlwifi driver missing (Ubuntu 18.04) (Linux Kernel 5.3.0-28-generic)

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, iwlwifi

Long story short, I accidentally deleted a part of my ubuntu-desktop trying to remove KDE. I tried to reinstall the missing packages through the virtual terminal but it didn't work as there was no internet connection (WiFI was working fine on the desktop). I tried `nmcli dev` but neither the Ethernet nor wireless device was shown.

I checked for the network controller using `sudo lspci` and `lshw -C network` and it popped up both times. It's a Intel Wireless 3160.

I then thought it was because I was missing the firmware so I went onto Windows (I have a Windows 10 dual-boot) and downloaded the firmware from the Intel website onto my USB.

I then went back into the Linux virtual terminal and copied the firmware to `/lib/firmware`. The Intel guide said to check the kernel configuration to check if Config_FW_Loader is on but I'm not sure how to do that. I checked the firmware directory and the firmware I downloaded is on there but it's the only one in green text.

I then tried to load the driver. I did `lsmod` and I couldn't see the wireless driver so I then did `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` to see:

> modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
>   modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

I tried `sudo modprobe iwlmvm` and I got something different:

> modeprobe: FATAL: Module iwlmvm not found in directory /lib/module/5.3.0-28-generic.

I don't know what to do from here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: iwlwifi should already be in the kernel therefore it would not appear separately.

Comment: @K7AAY ok okay, but why doesn't the terminal show a device when I do `nmcli dev`? I thought it was because the drivers weren't working, it must be something else then?

Comment: @K7AAY Btw, when I do `lshw -class network` both the wireless and ethernet controllers are labeled "unclaimed". Which makes me think this is a problem with the drivers.

Comment: Seems likely, but I continue to not have a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Booted up an older version of the kernel from grub. Wireless still didn't work but ethernet did. I was then able to redownload ubuntu-desktop.